# Stack.peek() returns correct value but function says it is not

Tags: python-3.x, stack

I have a problem in my code, where I have a condition, but it always returns false even when given the correct conditions. This problem is the balanced parentheses problem. If you take a look in my application code, I have 3 `elif` statements, where I specify the conditions. I figured out that the problem isn't with `.pop()` or the first condition, but with the second condition. When i used `print(stack.peek())` I can see that it returns the correct `self._top` that makes the `elif`statement run. But for some reason, the `elif` statement doesn't run. I'm really lost, can anyone help me on this?

Here is my stack code:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value
        self._link = None

    def value(self):
        return self._value

    def link(self):
        return self._link

    def newlink(self, node):
    self._link = node

    def __str__(self):
        return self._value


class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self._top = None
        self._length = 0

    def empty(self):
        if self._length == 0:
            return True
        return False

    def push(self, value):
        if self._top == None:
            self._top = ListNode(value)
            self._length += 1
        else:
            new_node = ListNode(value)
            new_node._link = self._top
            self._top = new_node
            self._length += 1

    def pop(self):
        node = self._top
        if self._top == None:
            return None
        else:
            nextNode = node._link
            self._top = nextNode
            self._length -= 1

    def peek(self):
        if self._top == None:
            return None
        return self._top

    def __str__(self):
        _list = []
        node = self._top

        while node != None:
            _list.append(node.value())
            node = node._link

        return f'{_list}'
```

Here is my appication code:

```
import my_version_of_stack as s


def is_parentheses_matched(expression):
    list_expression = list(expression)
    stack = s.Stack()

    for element in list_expression:
        if element == '{' or element == '[' or element == '(':
            stack.push(element)
        

        elif element == ']' and  stack.peek() == '[':
            stack.pop()

        elif element == '}' and stack.peek() == '{':
            stack.pop()

        elif element == ')' and stack.peek() == '(':
            stack.pop()


return stack.empty()
```

Comment: You're referring to `elif element == ']' and  stack.peek() == '[':`? If the body of that check isn't running, and you know that `stack.peek() == '['` is true, then that means that `element == ']'` must be False, or the condition above it was true.

Comment: Wait, `_top` is a `ListNode`, not a string. That comparison will never be true. `peek` should end in `return self._top._value`, or `return str(self._top)`. The `__str__` method of `ListNode` was hiding that bug.